# Some Clarification ε close from Terence Tao's Analysis 1

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

So in Terence Tao's amazing book Analysis 1 he introduces the concept of ε close to aid in the understanding of Absolute Value. I have some trouble understanding the following on Proposition 2

```
(d) Let ε,δ > 0. If x and y are ε-close and z and w are δ-close, then x+z and y+w are (ε + δ)-close 
and x-z and y-w are also (ε + δ) close
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't understand what it means to be $\epsilon$-close? I assume that you have some kind of absolute value/distance function $d$ given. Then $x$ and $y$ are $\epsilon$-close just means that $d(x,y) \leq \epsilon$. Then you can show the statement by using the triangle inequality.
Intuitively, the distance function is something similar to the usual distance function on $\mathbb{R}$. For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ with the usual absolute value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood the definition of ε-close. ε-close being the radius around say x and that the distance between x and y can only be at most equal to ε. What I have trouble understanding is how  x-z and y-w are also (ε + δ) close?

Comment: Since addition is defined on whatever space you're working on, I'll just explain the real case to you, so $x,y,z,w$ are real numbers and $d$ is defined using the usual absolute value. You have the triangle inequality $\forall x,y,: |x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$. So $d(x-z,y-w) = |x-z-(y-w)| = |x-z-y+w| = |x-y + w - z| \leq |x-y| + |w-z| \leq \epsilon + \delta$ by assumption that $x,y$ are $\epsilon$-close and $z,w$ are $\delta$-close.

Comment: Thank you so much. That cleared a lot. Thanks again for the detailed breakdown.